# Change suffix label on decimal grid in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.18, grids-graticules

I want to change my suffix label on decimal grid/measured grid coordinates for a map canvas in the print composer from "N" or "E" to "m.N" and "m.E". How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

While some more input on your side would have been helpful, here is the solution:

Go to `draw coordinates` in your map canvas' properties and change it to `custom/user defined`. Click the greek "E" next to it and enter

`@grid_number ||if(@grid_axis='x',' m.E.',' m.N.')`

Comment: thank you..it's works. but..how if I want just to display corner suffix label and leave the others decimal grid without suffix

Comment: Plant two grids atop of each other, one with the lines only, one with the coordinates of the corners only. Needs some fiddling with the intervall, the second one.

Answer (score 0):

For separate axises

1. use custom format @ draw coordinates
2. in expression based annotation, do the following expression

case
when @grid_axis = 'x'
then(@grid_number/1000) || (' E' )
when @grid_axis = 'y'
then (@grid_number/1000) || (' S')
end
(grid number was divided by 1000 if you need km s)